# Mysql error in Phusion Passenger in rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I am facing this error only in deployment.  In fact, in the deployment server, the `rails db production` works fine.  But on loading the app through the browser, this is the error I get:

```
Error message:
    (Mysql2::Error)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

The production log just shows `Connecting to database specified by database.yml` in a loop.

This is a shared hosting service, and they have been unable to figure out the problem.  Any idea what could be the reason?

I have to mention that this app was working fine until 6 hours back, and there were no changes made to the app for more than a day.

Comment: Are you using SELinux? See if there are errors in /var/log/audit/audit.log. Also look at http://www.seifeet.com/2012/09/ruby-apache-on-centos-63.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your production environment is correctly set up (gems, keys, database, ...). Maybe you installed the wrong version of the mysql2 gem?
2. Double-check your `database.yml` file for any typos.
3. It might also be possible that it takes too long to establish the connection with the database. Try to increase the `timeout` and the `pool` size.

Look additionally here: http://davidlesches.com/blog/fixing-a-connecting-to-database-specified-by-database-yml-loop

Some further questions:

- Have you tried to run your server in production mode on your local
  machine?
- Is the app working in test mode on the server?
- Are there any MySQL or Phusion Passenger log files you can share with us?

Comment: The application was fine until yesterday.  `rails db production` also connects to the right db.  And, from David's blog, even `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` returned `true`.

Comment: Can you share with us your log files (MySQL, Passenger)?

Comment: It's in a shared server, I don't have access to either of those logs.  The only logs I get are in Apache which show this: `Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner ( (Mysql2::Error))
[ pid=2549 thr=18798720 file=utils.rb:176 time=2015-01-28 02:38:38.450 ]: *** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner ( (Mysql2::Error)) (process 2549, thread #):
  from /home4/indiahi1/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/client.rb:24:in `initialize_e`

Comment: Try `rails console production` and then type in `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` to check if you are really connecting to the correct database. Maybe try to upgrade the `mysql2` gem from version `0.3.15` to the current version `0.3.17` if you are able to do this.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` shows the correct db.  But, upgrading to 0.3.17 throws a slightly different error - `Could not initialize MySQL client library`.  Does that help?

Comment: Not really. Are you trying all these commands with the correct account and can you share your `database.yml` file with us?

Comment: There are multiple db users, but only one account user in the server.  Account credentials are fine.  To confirm, the server runs in WEBrick completely fine in the server (in production mode too).  Sharing the database.yml contents: `production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ih1_ih
  pool: 5
  username: ih1_booking
  password: random
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306`

Comment: Try to increase the `pool` size to something higher like `25`. If this doesn't help try to restart your server even if this isn't really a solution or ask your server provider for access to the log files.

Comment: Increasing pool size didn't help.  And, since it's hosted on a shared server, no access to restart server.  Yes, I am trying to ask them for log files.  The issue has to be on the Passenger side, right?

Comment: I hope that at least the log files of Phusion Passenger are more informative than `Mysql2::Error`.

Comment: Since it's a shared server, no access to the Passenger logs.  The hosting support team recommends: Please, try reinstalling the mysql2 gem with the options `--with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config`.  I wonder how this will help since the app works fine in production mode in the server.  It's only deployment that's the problem.

Comment: You mean it is working in production mode on your local machine but not on the server?

Comment: It runs fine in production mode in the server if I run it using WEBrick like this `rails s -e production`.  Just doesn't work when it is deployed by Passenger.

Comment: Which service provider are you using and what about your Apache config?

Comment: The hosting service is JustHost.  Anyway, it's working fine now without any change from our end.  I guess they've fixed their problem.  Thanks.